# SpectralClustering() on nested circles returns mismatched labels

Tags: python, scikit-learn

After implementing Spectral clustering algorithm from sklearn, the predicted labels mismatches.

I have created a data set of 100 observations, which includes points on circles with radius 1 and 2.5, 50 points each. When we plot the data it looks like nested circles.

```py
clustering=SpectralClustering(n_clusters=2,eigen_solver='arpack',affinity="nearest_neighbors",random_state=1).fit(data)
data['labels']=clustering.labels_

plt.scatter(data['x'],data['y'],c=data['labels'])
```

[image]
[image]

Points on circles should have distinct cluster labels. Help me in getting right labels.

Answer (score 0):

By iterating the parameter n_neighbors in SpectralClustering(), I was able to get desired result.